# How to separate Gender As MALE AND FEMALE in sql server while having the Datatype of Gender is INT

Tags: sql-server

I want to separate the gender AS MALE and FEMALE in the database and the data type which I'm using for the gender is INT.

```
Gender    
------      
1
2
```

recording the data like this

```
Gender
------
Male
Female
```

Now I want the data in this form in a stored procedure.

Comment: I don't follow what the issue is, can you expand a bit more?

Comment: I really hope your *bit* pun was intended, @HoneyBadger :)

Comment: You say your data is a `bit`, however, a `bit` cannot store the value `2`. A (non-Nullable) `bit` can only have the value `0` and `1`. How are you storing the value `2`?

Comment: @Larnu it was, glad someone picked it up ;)

Comment: @Larnu Pardon me for that, the data type is INT.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE`:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    ID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(45),
    Gender BIT
    );

INSERT INTO Users VALUES
(1, N'User1', 1),
(2, N'User2', 0);

SELECT *,
       CASE Gender
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Male'
       WHEN 0 THEN 'Female'
       ELSE
       'Unknown' END
FROM Users;
```

Results:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------+
| ID | Name  | Gender | Gender |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
|  1 | User1 | True   | Male   |
|  2 | User2 | False  | Female |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
```

The **[BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** data type is an integer data type that can take a value of `1`, `0`, or `NULL`.

Comment: @GuidoG Mybe the column is `NOT NULL`

Comment: @GuidoG Alright done

Comment: much better now

Answer (score 0):

You can use 0 or 1 for bit columns
If you provide a value likee 2 then it will be stored as 1 in the table column
So it is important you only use 0 and 1

I used 0 for female data and 1 for males

Here is the stored procedure code

```
create procedure PeopleByGender (
        @gender bit -- 1 male, 0 female
    )
    as
    if @gender is null
        --select * from people 
        select * from people where gender is null
    else
        select * from people where gender = @gender
    go
```

Here is how to list females by stored procedure

```
exec PeopleByGender 0
```

Comment: What if the column gender is nullable ? In that case your procedure cannot fetch all that are null

Comment: Hi GuidoG, I modified the stored procedure inside. Please check. Thanks for taking care on the NULL option

Comment: so now you return all people if you pass null as parameter. Maybe this is intended and maybe not we dont know with the few information the OP gave us. I would have returned all people where gender is null in that case

Comment: Maybe we can change the IF clause for NULL case as follows: if @gender is null
 select * from people where gender is null

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

`SELECT 
     IIF(Gender IS NULL, 'Others', IIF(Gender = 1, 'Male', 'Female')) Gender 
 FROM Users;`

Comment: This suffers from the same problem/assumption that Sami's initially did. If the value of `Gender` is `NULL` (or not 1) then the person will always be female. Considering the OP is storing the value `2` in a "`bit`" datatype (`2` can't be stored in a `bit`), they could well have a range of values other than `1` and `2`.